# Why is my single `Entity` object is taken as a list into account?

Tags: python

I have two classes as follows:

```
class Coordinate(object):

    def __init__(self, x, y):
        self.X = x
        self.Y = y

    def some_other_function():
        pass

class Entity(object):

    def __init__(self, coordinate, radius):
        self.Coordinate = coordinate
        self.Radius = radius
```

Later in the `main` function, a bunch of `Entity` objects are created like:

```
obstacle1_coord = Coordinate(6.0, 8.0)
obstacle2_coord = Coordinate(10.0, 8.0)
obstacle3_coord = Coordinate(14.0, 8.0)
obstacle4_coord = Coordinate(18.0, 8.0)

obstacle1 = Entity(obstacle1_coord, 0.5)
obstacle2 = Entity(obstacle2_coord, 0.5)
obstacle3 = Entity(obstacle3_coord, 0.5)
obstacle4 = Entity(obstacle4_coord, 0.5)
obstacles = [obstacle1, obstacle2, obstacle3, obstacle4]
```

Thus, each item of `obtacles` list is just an `Entity` whose `Coordinate.X` and/or `Coordinate.Y` attributes should be accessible. But when I later write

```
for item in obstacles:
        a = plt.Circle((item.Coordinate.X, item.Coordinate.Y), radius=item.Radius)
        ax.add_artist(a)
```

The interpreter returns the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "CompAssoCoop.py", line 284, in <module>
    a = plt.Circle((item.coordinate.X, item.coordinate.Y), radius=item.Radius)
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'coordinate'
```

I also use the `obstacles` list in a function as below:

```
def MAPF(lambda_mapf_attr, lambda_mapf_repl, curr_coor_X, curr_coor_Y, goal_coor_X, goal_coor_Y, obstacles, peers):
    attr = lambda_mapf_attr*math.hypot(curr_coor_X - goal_coor_X, curr_coor_Y - goal_coor_Y)**2
    repl = 0
    for item in obstacles.append(peers) or []:
        repl += 1/math.hypot(curr_coor_X - item.Coordinate.X, curr_coor_Y - item.Coordinate.Y)**2
    repl *= lambda_mapf_repl
    return attr + repl
```

in which `peers` is a list of some other `Entity` objects.

What I am missing here?

Comment: Context is missing - as presented that code does not cause the issue described.

Comment: @user2864740: I added the function in which the `obstacles` list of used. Is that relevant to the issue?

Comment: See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/append-extend-python/ (append = “add one”, extend = “concat many”)

Comment: I think this traceback isn't for this code. I executed your code and it's running OK

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This line is frankly horrible, appending a `list` to another `list` **inside** a for loop definition like that is a recipe for disaster.

`for item in obstacles.append(peers) or []:`

It would be better to use:

```
obstacles_and_peers = obstacles.extend(peers)
for item in obstacles_and_peers:
...
```

or

```
obstacles_and_peers = obstacles + peers
for item in obstacles_and_peers:
...
```

Comment: While this is a good point about code style, the *error* happens because `append` was used rather than `extend` (or `+`). This puts sub-lists into the list, rather than concatenating elements from the other list.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel you're right, I should have been more explicit.